# shell expansion (A|B) in filenames?

Tags: bash, shell, bash-expansion

Is it possible to expand an `or` choice in the shell when reading a file for example.

What I mean by this is that, for instance, `grep` supports syntax like `(A|B)` to match A or B in a file.

Similarly, if I have these files:

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
file4.txt
file5.txt
```

I could do `cat file{1..5}.txt` in `bash`, as it expands the range. Is there an equivalent way to do this for just a couple of files?

E.g. `cat file(1|5).txt` and only print those 2?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The standard file name globbing pattern to match *a digit* is `[0-9]`.  This matches a single digit:

```
cat file[0-9].txt
```

To select only two of these:

```
cat file[25].txt
```

For larger numbers than 9, brace expansion will be useful (but see note below for the difference between globbing patterns and brace expansions):

```
cat file{25..60}.txt
```

Again, brace expansion allows for individual numbers as well:

```
cat file{12,45,900,xyz}.txt
```

(note that in the example above, the brace expansion does not involve an arithmetic loop, but just generates names based on the strings provided).

In `bash`, with the `extglob` shell option enabled (`shopt -s extglob`), the following will also work:

```
cat file@(12|45|490|foo).txt
```

The `@(...)` pattern will match any one of the included `|`-delimited patterns.

---

The difference between globbing patterns as `[...]` and `@(...)` and brace expansions, is that a brace expansion is *generated on the command line* and may not actually match any existing names in the current directory.  A filename globbing pattern will match names, but the shell won't complain if not all possible name exist. If *no* matching name exists, the pattern will remain be unexpanded, unless also the `nullglob` shell option is set, in which case the pattern is removed.

Example:

```
touch file1

ls file[0-9]
```

Here, only the file listing for `file1` will be shown.

With `ls file{0..9}`, `ls` would complain about not finding `file0`, `file2` etc.

In the following example, the first command will only touch *existing names* that matches the given pattern, while the second line will create files that does not already exist:

```
touch file[0-9]

touch file{0..9}
```

Comment: @thecarpy I'm sorry, but that is not a pattern that would match e.g. `file45.txt`. The bracket expression `[...]` works just as in regular expression but uses `!` in place of `^` for saying "not in". A `[...]` pattern will always match a single character.

Comment: You are right! BTW, my `{1,2}` is not POSIX compliant either ... learned a few new things today!

Comment: The fact that brace expansions need not match real files can be extremely useful, if you're using it to (for example) generate patterns to pass to `grep`, generate URLs to pass to `curl`, and so on... but it can also be confusing to people who are used to working with globs.

Comment: @Kevin Correct. A brace expansion does not need to be about filenames.

Answer (score 8):

The syntax to use is `file{1,2}` which will evaluate to `file1` and `file2`.

```
$ ls
$ touch file{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
$ ls
file1  file2  file3  file4  file5  file6  file7  file8  file9
```

As Inian pointed out below as well ... it would be easier to do `touch file{1..9}` in this example case ...

```
$ ls
$ touch file{1..9}
$ ls
file1  file2  file3  file4  file5  file6  file7  file8  file9
```

You can also use multiple expressions, like:

```
$ ls
$ touch file{1..9}{a..z}
$ ls
file1a file1b file1c
[...]
file9x file9y file9z
```

Yes, the above will create 234 (`9` times `26`) files.

Comment: This `file{1,2}`  syntax is also convenient to rename files : `mv some_very_long_filename.txt{,.bak}`

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can use brace expansion in the `bash` shell. For just the couple of files just do `file{1..2}` or just as `file{1,2}`

Or if you are worried about the files not being there in some cases, just do a simple loop,

```
for file in file{1..4}.txt; do
    [ -f "$file" ] || continue
    echo "$file" # Do other actions on file here
done
```

Or if just concatenating is your only operation on the files and if you are *unsure* which files could not be present at any point of time, just `cat` them and suppress the errors. Re-directing standard error to `/dev/null` would suppress the errors if the file is not available.

```
cat file{1,5}.txt 2>/dev/null
```

or use the glob expression `file[15]` which does not complain about the errors if the file was not found.

```
cat file[15].txt
```

Comment: Nope, no concerns about files not being there, I just wanted to show the content of 2 files numbered numerically, but that aren't consecutive, so the `file{1,5}` comma syntax was all I was missing!